# Cannot Get ID of user after login using User.Identity.GetUserId()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` in my application.

The user can Log In and can only see his/her own controller.

Because I've added attributes (`[Authorize(Roles = "1")]`) and this works fine as well.

But I can't get the user Id by using `string users = User.Identity.GetUserId();`.

`users` is always `null`, and I don't know why.

I am not using default login template.

And one more thing, after login I've done something like this

```
if (User.IsInRole("1"))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Supplier");
}
else if (User.IsInRole("2"))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Site");
}
```

but it does not work as well. But when I login and go to controller which has `Authorize(Roles ="1")` in controller, it does not give any error or redirect to login page.

But when I login with the user (which has `Roles="2"`), I cannot access the controller with `Authorize(Roles="1")`.

This is how I have configured ASP.Net Identity:

```
public partial class Startup 
{ 
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) 
    { 
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
        { 
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, 
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Index") }); 
        } 
    }
}
```

**Update**
For Redirection based on Role I've updated my Controller/Action.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginView login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = (from u in db.logins
                        where u.user_name == login.user_name && u.user_password == login.user_password && u.isactive == 1
                        select new
                        {
                            u.user_name,
                            u.login_id,
                            u.user_type,
                            u.isactive
                        });

            if (user.FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.user_name, true);
                Session["UserName"] = user.FirstOrDefault().user_name;
                string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                return RedirectToAction("RedirectToDefault");
            }

            else
            {
                ViewBag.error = "User Does Not Exist";
                return View(login);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Credentials");
        }
        return View(login);
    }
```

And the in `RedirectToDefault` I've added:

```
public ActionResult RedirectToDefault()
    {

        String[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
        string id = User.Identity.GetUserId(); //<- this is null here as well.
        string name = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        if (roles.Contains("1"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Supplier");
        }
        else if (roles.Contains("2"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Site");
        }
```

and so on..

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to apply both `Authorize(Roles = "1")` and `Authorize(Roles = "2")` annotations in the Controllers/Actions you want to allow both groups to access.

Comment: @Tiramonium I know that but i want to Access the UserId by User.Identity.GetUserId(). I don't know why but it is always null. And for redirect purpose, User.IsInRole("1") does not work as well.

Comment: What does your `Startup.Auth.cs` look like - in other words, how is ASP.NET Identity configured for your site?  Also, @Tiramonium is saying that you probably need to have the `Authorize` attribute on your controller / action, otherwise the middleware may not execute, and therefore set the `User.Identity` for the request.

Comment: @BrendanGreen this is my `Startup.Auth.cs`

`public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Index")
            });
        }
    } `

Comment: That redirect - is that happening during signin (i.e. you want to redirect the use *at the time of login* to the different controller?  If so, the `User.Identity` property has NOT been set yet.  However, since you've already called into ASP.NET Identity, you'll have the information you need to make that decision.

Comment: I Solved the redirection problem by redirecting to another Action and IN that action i redirected to Different Controllers based on Role. But i still can't get the Userid. `User.Identity.GetUserId()` is always null. Even in the second action which i used to redirect according to user role.

Comment: @BrendanGreen does he need to set the authentication cookie to get his user identity id? I mean, by using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(string userName, string password);`

Comment: Please update the question, and post the relevent (complete!) sections of code.

Comment: @Tiramonium not if he's using ASP.NET Identity - there's a user manager signin manager that'll take care of that.  Although the questions doesn't detail how this all got setup.  The VS template will usually scaffold a lot of it for you.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Please see the edit.

Comment: Please note that, despite what you say, you are *not* using ASP.NET Identity at the moment in your application.  I suggest you checkout the documentaion and tutorials here: https://www.asp.net/identity, and then come back.  Your current implementation is very insecure, and possibly prone to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

From your incomplete code it looks like you are doing everything manually, selecting users from the db and so on.

Try using the SignInManager:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginView login)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login.Username, login.Password, false, shouldLockout: true);

        if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.user_name, true);
            //Session["UserName"] = user.FirstOrDefault().user_name;
            //string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            //These shouldn't be neede anymore
            return RedirectToAction("RedirectToDefault");
        }

        else
        {
            ViewBag.error = "User Does Not Exist";
            return View(login);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Credentials");
    }
    return View(login);
}
```

I would suggest that you read up on how Identity works, as it does everything for you, however you need to know how to access the data.

Comment: everything is working. `Authorize Attribute` as well. Now `Redirection based on Role` as well. But i still can't get the `User Id`. It is always `null`.

Comment: Could you post the login method?

Comment: You aren't really using Identity. What you are doing is manually checking in the database if the user exists, and handling all of that. As i try to explain in my answer, you have to use the SignInManager for this. SignInManager takes care of logging in the user properly, and checking if the user actually exists before doing so. I will edit my answer to try and clarify this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand now what you said. Can you please share a link or some code which could help me in this? I want to add Users in my `Login Table` with `User Types` which then will be considered as `User Roles` and at the end `Users` Can login and then redirected to their homepage based on `Role`. And on that homepage `Users` can only see their data.

Comment: I already have a database with `Login` table and necessary information. How can i use that table with `Identity` and `Custom Roles` in my case?
I am using `EF Designer from Database`.

Comment: If you don't have alot of entries i would suggest using the tables that Identity creates by itself. However if you really wanna do it with custom tables there may be a way to do this by binding it with Fluent API. However i would suggest that you create a new question for this.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132957/use-existing-tables-in-asp-net-identity-mvc-5].  Please see this link

Comment: I do believe that it would be easier for you to migrate your existing users to the Identity tables. I foresee alot of problems with using a custom table.

Comment: The worst part is that i spent 2 days on this thing and followed tutorials on every step. I got it all working even with `Custom Roles` according to my needs. And now you told me that user is not actually `Logged In`. Now I am back to step One. And I don't know what to do now.

Comment: If you followed a tutorial, and wired it up correctly (doesn't take much) you should have the following 5 tables, see if you have these first: AspNetRoles AspNetUserClaims AspNetUserLogins AspNetUserRoles andAspNetUsers

Comment: I followed tutorial which provided custom Login, not using default template. Now i have all those 5 tables in my existing database. But how can i remove extra fields and Add some fields in these tables and how can i change their name? Meaning how can i customize them according to my need?

Comment: It is fairly easy. I found a video showing it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPF2BINKhpY, however i'm not sure whether you are on MVC 5 and Identity 2 or .Net Core. However you could google the one you are using.

Comment: I'm using MVC 5 and Identity 2.

Comment: That video should help you then.

Comment: I have my `Custom Roles class`, after that `DB` query the `User.IsInRole("1")` works fine and i can get the `User_Name` as well by using `User.Identity.GetUserName()` but I i can't get the `User Id` by using `User.Identity.GetUserId()` and `Authorize` attribute works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user id through UserManager like:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(username, password);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar problem inside the "web app server blazor 8rc2"
after external login, /Account/Manage page, redirect to /Account/InvalidUser page, and get error:

Error: Unable to load user with ID '{userManager.GetUserId(principal)}'.

why externallogininfo return null!!!

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){ Input ??= new(); ReturnUrl ??= "/";

 if (RemoteError is not null)
 {
     RedirectManager.RedirectToWithStatus("/Account/Login", "Error from external provider: " + RemoteError);
     return;
 }

 var externalLoginInfo = await SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
 if (externalLoginInfo is null)//why return null!!!!!!
 {
     RedirectManager.RedirectToWithStatus("/Account/Login", "Error loading external login information.");
     return;
 }
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
.AddIdentityCookies();
```